# Is this estimation correct?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to estimate the following quantity
$$\frac{|e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}|x|}-e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}|x|}|^2}{|x|^2}$$
in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($\lambda>0$) where
$$\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}=\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}+i\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}}$$ with $\lambda_\varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda^2+\varepsilon^2}+\lambda}{2}$
Is it true that
$$\frac{|e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}|x|}-e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}|x|}|^2}{|x|^2}\leq \frac{C}{|x|^2}$$?

Answer (score 1):

The denumerator $Q$ of your expression can be written as
$$Q=\left|\exp\biggl(i\bigl(\sqrt{\lambda_\epsilon}-\sqrt\lambda\bigr)|x|-{\epsilon|x|\over 2\sqrt{\lambda_\epsilon}}\biggr)-1\right|^2\ .$$
When $\epsilon<0$ this can be become arbitrarily large for large $|x|$. When $\epsilon\geq0$ is guaranteed then $Q\leq4$, since $Q$ can be regarded as $|z-1|^2$ for some $z$ in the closed unit disk.

Comment: I have $\varepsilon>0$ so my estimation is true